# Using array_fill within a while loop

Tags: php

I'm attempting to build an array from multiple records (unknown how many records there could be at any one time) using a while loop and `array_fill` but it's not working the way I had hoped it would. It's overwriting the array with each record and then the only data in the array after the while loop finishes execution, is the last record loaded.

`$reward` is the variable being overwritten. Driving me nuts! I would like to see it build `$reward` into a merged array consisting of the (in this instance) 3 records that I'm querying for. But it's ending up being the last record found. What am I doing wrong?

```
while ($WhileLoop <= $PrizeCount) {
    print "<!-- Loop # [" . $WhileLoop . "] -->\n";
    $Prize1Credits = $PrizeRecord["Prize_Credits"];
    $print "<!-- Cred # [" . $Prize1Credits . "] -->\n";
    $Prize1ID = $PrizeRecord["Prize_ID"];
    print "<!-- ID # [" . $Prize1ID . "] -->\n";
    $reward = array_fill($ArrayIndex,$Prize1Credits,$Prize1ID);
    print "<!-- IND # [" . $ArrayIndex . "] -->\n";
    $ArrayIndex += $Prize1Credits;
    $WhileLoop++;
    $DBConnection->next_record();                
    $PrizeRecord = $DBConnection->Record;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

As you said you are overriding `$reward` array. You can use `+` operator on arrays to keep adding new records to `$reward`:

in your while loop:

```
$reward += array_fill($ArrayIndex,$Prize1Credits,$Prize1ID);
```

But to make this code more readable I would prefer a loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $Prize1Credits, $i++) {
  $reward[] = $Prize1ID;
}
// no need for $ArrayIndex
```

Comment: One of the first things I tried was the += operand, which throws a fatal "you can't use that operand with an array" type message. However, your for loop (switched the comma to a semi-colon after Prize1Credits) worked like a charm. Thanks man!

Comment: You're welcome. by the way, why do you iterate with a custom variable `$WhileLoop`? Is it not possible to iterate until $DBConnection->next_record() returns a value like: `while ($DBConnection->next_record())` ?